# Efficiently wiring together data and representation via GUI Control Factories?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, factory-pattern, data-representation

Lets say I have a class `StaticVehicleInformation` which holds "static" information about a vehicle, e.g. its type, serial-number or color.

Now I have a tracking application to track driving vehicles and show them on a map. In such a case `StaticVehicleInformation` is wrapped in a `DynamicVehicleEntry<? extends StaticVehicleInformation>`, which basically adds "dynamic" information such as currentPosition, speed or currentDriver. At the same time it has a method `<T extends StaticVehicleInformation> <T> getStaticVehicleInformation()` to return the wrapped static infos.

In my map or basically in any view showing different moving cars, thus mostly dealing with `List<DynamicVehicleEntry <? extends StaticVehicleInformation>`, I need to distinguish which actual type of vehicle I'm dealing with to show a different icon and so forth. So by having concrete `DynamicVehicleEntry` classes (`DynamicCarEntry extends DynamicVehicleEntry <StaticCarInformation>`, `DynamicMotorcycleEntry extends DynamicVehicleEntry <StaticMotorcycleInformation>`,...) I get different types of live-tracked vehicles, having different static and - if needed - specific "dynamic" attributes (within the subclasses of `DynamicVehicleEntry`).

Because of my goal to separate Data from UI, I've built a Factory returning different UI-Elements based on the type of `DynamicVehicleEntry` they should display:

```
// .... Factory....
public static Node createNewControlFromType(DynamicVehicleEntry <? extends StaticVehicleInformation> entry) {
    // from specific to general
    if (entry instanceof DynamicCarEntry) {
        return new CarControl(entry);
    } else if (entry instanceof DynamicMotorcycleEntry) {
        return new MotorcycleControl(entry);
    } else {
        // no concrete UI-Method found, so return a generic Control showing a dummy-icon
        // and only the most generic information common to every DynamicVehicleEntry and the wrapped StaticVehicleInformation
        return new GenericControl(entry);
    }
}
```

`instanceOf` smells, and I think type-erasure of generics might also break my neck. Any ideas how I should solve this assuming I cannot modify the `Static...Information` and `Static...Information` classes?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I've done some extensive search on it and did not find any better solution, especially if one cannot modify existing classes, as it would be needed by a Visitor Pattern. As noted in the comments [here](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.VisitorVersusInstanceOf) one can do some reflection magic to do the same, but from my understanding instanceof is "light"-reflection anyway.